# use the same classes in WCF client and server

Tags: c#, wcf

I am just learning wfc and have a question. I have write test class:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class TestClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public TestKind Kind { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<TestClass> Childs { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public TestClass Parent { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Value { set; get; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        Childs = new List<TestClass>();
    }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class TestKind
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { set; get; }
}
```

Kinds are stored in cache and need to be loaded from it.
The target is to use this classes in WFC client and server. There is not problem at server. It easy starts and have only one method returns a list of TestClass:

```
AutoResetEvent infinity = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8989/test");
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyRemote), baseAddress))
{
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
    {
        HttpGetEnabled = true,
        MetadataExporter =
        {
            PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Default
        }
    };
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    host.Open();
    infinity.WaitOne();
}
```

code of server implementation:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "testSvc")]
public interface IRemote
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<TestClass> GetAll();
}

public class Remote : IRemote
{
    public List<TestClass> GetAll()
    {
        return Program.classes;
    }
}
```

But then I trying to add reference to it in client, VS creating new TestClass class with a fields like:

```
...
[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
private string IdField;

[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
private ConsoleApplication7.ServiceReference1.TestKind KindField;

[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
private ConsoleApplication7.ServiceReference1.TestClass ParentField;
...
```

So the question is how to code a client to connect to server and get the list of TestClass entities (don't generate another classes). Possible to extend TestClass? Or where another methods?

Comment: If you put your datacontract classes inside a separate assembly and reference that assembly at the server and client, then you can make it easier by configurating `Reuse types in referenced assemblies` when configuring the service reference on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[KnownType]`:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "testSvc")]
[KnownType(typeof(TestClass))]
public interface IRemote
```

That will use your types during deserialization (not create new ones) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx